# Mongoose 'populate()' not populating

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So Im building a simple application with the MEARN stack.

The problem is that i want to have the user's information (name,email, etc...) to be put in the 'user' property in the product , and it's not working (Postman request return 500 status Server error) , i don't know what i'm doing wrong , thanks in advance! my code snippets :

My User Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user',UserSchema)
```

my Product Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema)
```

and my request :

```
router.get('/:id', async (req,res) => {
     try {
          const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate('user')
          res.json(product)
     } catch (err) {
          res.status(500).send('Server Error')
     } 
 })
```

Comment: The `err` value should tell you what the problem is, but I would guess it's that you're using the wrong model name in your `ref`. It should be `ref: 'user'`

Comment: @JohnnyHK thank you so much ! that was the source of the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ref` value needs to match the name of the model `user` references. So you need to change it to:

```
user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path:`populate({path:'user'})` Try :

```
router.get('/:id', async (req,res) => {
     try {
          const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate({path:'user'})
          res.json(product)
     } catch (err) {
          res.status(500).send('Server Error')
     } 
 })
```

Comment: Server error , it comes from the catch bloc in the trycatch